# MVC5 Razor View always show the error: "the type arguments cannot be inferred from usage"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've updated my project from MVC4 to MVC5 and since then I'm getting this error message though it runs perfectly

This is my Web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="bundleTransformer">
        <section name="core" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Configuration.CoreSettings, BundleTransformer.Core" />
        <section name="less" type="BundleTransformer.Less.Configuration.LessSettings, BundleTransformer.Less" />
        <section name="yui" type="BundleTransformer.Yui.Configuration.YuiSettings, BundleTransformer.Yui" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="jsEngineSwitcher">
        <section name="core" type="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.Configuration.CoreConfiguration, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core" />
        <section name="msie" type="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie.Configuration.MsieConfiguration, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="Error">
    <listeners>
        <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" fileName="sgew.log" formatter="Text Formatter" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollSizeKB="102400" maxArchivedFiles="10" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
        <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" template="Timestamp: {timestamp(local)}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}" name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
        <add switchValue="All" name="Error">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
            </listeners>
        </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
        <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
        <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
        <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
            </listeners>
        </errors>
    </specialSources>
</loggingConfiguration>

<exceptionHandling>
    <exceptionPolicies>
        <add name="ErrorPolicy">
            <exceptionTypes>
                <add name="Exception" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" postHandlingAction="ThrowNewException">
                    <exceptionHandlers>
                        <add name="Wrap Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WrapHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" exceptionMessage="Erro da aplicação" wrapExceptionType="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                    </exceptionHandlers>
                </add>
            </exceptionTypes>
        </add>
    </exceptionPolicies>
</exceptionHandling>

<appSettings>
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableSitemapsXml" value="false" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeAssembliesForScan" value="AspNetMvcApplication" />
</appSettings>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SgewContext" connectionString="Data Source=MYCONNECTIONSTRING" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TenantContext" connectionString="Data Source=MYCONNECTIONSTRING" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
            <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" timeout="5" />
    <httpModules>
        <add name="OnePerRequestModule" type="Ninject.OnePerRequestModule" />
    </httpModules>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="SGEW" loginUrl="~/login" timeout="60" />
    </authentication>
    <caching>
        <outputCacheSettings>
            <outputCacheProfiles>
                <!-- Mantem o cache das views que usarem esse perfil. Valor em segundos. -->
                <add name="cachePrincipal" duration="1" varyByParam="None" />
                <!-- Mantem o cache das views que usarem esse perfil. Valor em segundos. -->
                <add name="cacheSecundario" duration="1" varyByParam="tipoSelecao;tipoEntidade" />
            </outputCacheProfiles>
        </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
        <remove name="RoleManager" />
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add name="LessAssetHandler" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="BundleTransformer.Less.HttpHandlers.LessAssetHandler, BundleTransformer.Less" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <hiddenSegments>
                <add segment="ClearScript.V8" />
            </hiddenSegments>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWcfCepService" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://srvdsnv/wcfcep/WcfCepService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWcfCepService" contract="CepService.IWcfCepService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWcfCepService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>

<bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
    <less>
        <jsEngine name="MsieJsEngine" />
    </less>
    <core>
        <assetHandler disableClientCache="true" disableServerCache="true" serverCacheDurationInMinutes="15" />
        <css>
            <minifiers>
                <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
                <add name="YuiCssMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Yui.Minifiers.YuiCssMinifier, BundleTransformer.Yui" />
            </minifiers>
            <translators>
                <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
                <add name="LessTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator, BundleTransformer.Less" />
            </translators>
            <fileExtensions>
                <add fileExtension=".css" assetTypeCode="Css" />
                <add fileExtension=".less" assetTypeCode="Less" />
            </fileExtensions>
            <postProcessors>
                <add name="UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor" type="BundleTransformer.Core.PostProcessors.UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor, BundleTransformer.Core" useInDebugMode="false" />
            </postProcessors>
        </css>
        <js>
            <minifiers>
                <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
                <add name="YuiJsMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Yui.Minifiers.YuiJsMinifier, BundleTransformer.Yui" />
            </minifiers>
            <translators>
                <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
            </translators>
            <fileExtensions>
                <add fileExtension=".js" assetTypeCode="JavaScript" />
            </fileExtensions>
        </js>
    </core>
</bundleTransformer>

<jsEngineSwitcher xmlns="http://tempuri.org/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Configuration.xsd">
    <core>
        <engines>
            <add name="MsieJsEngine" type="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie.MsieJsEngine, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie" />
            <add name="V8JsEngine" type="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.V8JsEngine, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8" />
        </engines>
    </core>
</jsEngineSwitcher>

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="BundleTransformer.Core" publicKeyToken="973c344c93aac60d" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.9.25.0" newVersion="1.9.25.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.0.0" newVersion="3.3.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core" publicKeyToken="c608b2a8cc9e4472" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.0.0" newVersion="1.2.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="MsieJavaScriptEngine" publicKeyToken="a3a2846a37ac0d3e" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.0.0" newVersion="1.5.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I'm looking for an answer since last week and I can't find one :/

I have already checked all the assemblies and update my NuGet packages but doesn't seen to help.

As I saw in another post, I've set  but even so the red line doesn't disappear.

Comment: Is your code failing on a particular line or view? Or just whenever views are rendered?

Comment: Everytime I use a Html Helper or ViewBag I got that red underline but the View renders just fine. It's only on design time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer and forgot to post here sorry!

It was a problem with my ancestor base page view. Silly thing but took me a while to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I installed the RazorEngine with the package manager console. After deleting a part of my web.config, my project was working perfectly again. Let's hope this is the fix for you too.

My web.config then

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

so I had to remove this part

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```